# Making my own custom rules yaml linting tool with Python

Tags: python, yaml, lint, yamllint

I came across a python program at my work that supposedly allowed previous guy to lint a kubernetes deployment file against some custom rules. (program didn't look correct though)

```
file_path = "path/to/k8s/config.yml"

# custom rule
custom_rules = [
    {"type": "json", "path": "metadata.labels.app", "value": "my-app"} ]
```

Once rule and target file in place, it is referring to a library **kubeval** to run a `validate` method.

```
try:
    results = kubeval.validate(file_path, rules=custom_rules)
    print("Configuration file is valid")
```

The program didn't have any import but after looking at it I assumed that it should import something like **"kubeval"**. Problem is, that I don't see any python library in PyPi with Kubeval name.

```
$ pip3 install kubeval
Collecting kubeval
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kubeval (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for kubeval
```

Am I missing something or digging in wrong direction? I don't think this program ever worked! However people claim it did.

Note: Any guidance here would be appreicated. I could maybe start trying making my own method that validates against these JSON rules but I am unsure where to start with that. Or maybe I am getting the packages wrong!

Comment: Probably a Python wrapper around [kubeval](https://github.com/instrumenta/kubeval/), which is written in Go.

Comment: Interesting to check the content to conform to rules, but not that the filename conforms to have the recommended file extension for files containing a YAML document (which has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006 ).

Comment: @Anthon There's no diff between yaml or yml both are same. It used to be an OS things where extensions could only be of 3 letters, so shouldn't really matter if file names are confirmed.